# Execute a function if a targeted element is in sight or is passed by scrolling in a overflow div

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is possible but how can I execute a function if a certain element with a certain id is in sight or is passed in a overflow div regardless how fast you scroll.

[Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciO9T.png)

I try many times but I can't figure how I can do this?

This is my code

```js
/*document.querySelector('#trigger'); ?????*/

function triggerisInSightOrIsPassed(){
  //???
  alert('Trigger is in sight or is passed');
}
```

```css
#container{
  background-color: purple;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1{
  color: gold;
}

#trigger{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1 id='trigger'>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current position of the `trigger` element using it's [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) and you can get the current scroll position using [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

So your `trigger` element would be inside view, as soon as the `scrollTop` and `offsetHeight` of the container is larger than the triggers `offsetTop`

I did change the alert to `console.log` so that it would be less intrusive :)

To detect the changes in the scrolling position, you can just attach a listener to the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event

```js
const triggerElement = document.querySelector('#trigger');

document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('scroll', function( e ) {
  if (e.target.scrollTop + e.target.offsetHeight > triggerElement.offsetTop) {
    console.log('Trigger is in sight or is passed');
  }
} );
```

```css
#container{
  background-color: purple;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1{
  color: gold;
}

#trigger{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1 id="trigger">random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
  <h1>random</h1>
</div>
```